# Trying to get one image field to pop up images from another field using lightbox2 in Views

Tags: javascript

I have two image fields in a View that shows one of the image fields and the other image is excluded from display.

I would like to click on the image that's displayed and have the other image popup using Lightbox2 which I have installed.

I'm a little bit confused because there's different information about how to go about doing that.

I got as far as rewriting the output of the displayed image field to the popup image field using replacement tokens and I put 'lightbox' for rel text. But nothing happens. The displayed image doesn't become a link.

What am I missing?

Comment: I also read about the method of making both image fields excluded from display and then adding a Lightbox trigger field but when I try to do this and add a Lightbox trigger field I get a warning saying "The handler for this item is broken or missing and cannot be used. If a module provided the handler and was disabled, re-enabling the module may restore it. Otherwise, you should probably delete this item." as soon as I add the Lightbox trigger field.

Comment: Ok, so I've got as far as getting the Lightbox trigger to be added after uninstalling Lightbox2 and installing the latest dev version but I'm not seeing any Replacement Pattern tokens being listed at all for some reason...

Comment: Ok, so now I have the trigger image showing up as clickable but when I click on it, nothing happens and nothing pops up. The url it's linking to just has something like this at the end of the url:
    `%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%23lightbox-popup-1`  
Does anyone know what I'm still missing to get this to work? I feel like I'm getting close yet so far...

Comment: What a pain in the ass. I had to apply [this patch](https://drupal.org/comment/7836831#comment-7836831) manually in order to get the lightbox popup to finally show.  

Now the only problem is that I'm getting an error message on the views page:  
  
    `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in lightbox2_handler_field_lightbox2->render() (line 191 of /var/www/sites/all/modules/contrib/lightbox2/lightbox2_handler_field_lightbox2.inc).`  
  
And line 191 show this piece of new code that was added as part of the patch:  
  
    `$imgsrc = $matches[1];`  
  
Anyway, I'm getting there. So close...